# Removing items from NSMutableArray when hooking Swift not working

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Here is my code:

```
-(NSArray*)buttons {
    NSArray *buttons = %orig;
    NSMutableArray *mutableItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:buttons];
    [mutableItems objectAtIndex:2];
    return mutableItems;
}
```

I am trying to remove an object from an NSArray, but that NSArray is in a Swift class. I am having no trouble getting anything else in that Swift class to change, but I can't remove any objects from the NSArray. I don't get any errors, but the changes I make simply don't have any effect. This is for a jailbreak tweak.

Comment: Did you use the debugger to isolate the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `[mutableItems objectAtIndex:2]` with `[mutableItems removeObjectAtIndex:2]`.

Full example:

```
-(NSArray*)buttons {
    NSArray* buttons = @[@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d"];
    NSMutableArray *mutableItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:buttons];
    [mutableItems removeObjectAtIndex:2];
    return mutableItems;
}
```

The `mutableItems` array will contain a,b,d.

Comment: This still isn't working, and I dont understand why i need to add a, b,c and d to the NSArray if i didnt make it

Comment: @Squ1dd13Dev this is just an example, since I don't know what `%orig` is. It illustrates how to remove the object at index 2 from the array. I thought your initial question was how to remove an object form an NSArray.

Comment: Your answer still isn't working for some reason though.

Comment: @Squ1dd13Dev If you copy my code above, how many values are in `mutableItems`? 3 or 4?

Comment: @Squ1dd13Dev Edit the question to post the complete code you have now.  I.e. how you create the %orig, etc.

Comment: Dude if `%orig` has "0-19 items in it", then you cannot just remove item at index 2. When %orig only has 0, 1 or 2 items, that will cause a crash. Also, the code shown here is correct... if you're having a problem, you should share more of your code.